# Reading diagrams/images/schemas from a Word document in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-automation

I want to copy the content of one word document into other word document.
So, I full read a word document like it says here, and it seems to work:

http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-parse-the-text-content-from-microsoft-word-document/

Then, the resulted string from full reading, I embedded it into a new created word document like it says here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/ and this also seems to work.

1. How to get the diagrams/images/schemas from the first word document in order to get them in the 2nd word document?

I displayed the links instead the code, cose I have see other posts like that. But if it's not ok, I will paste my code.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, your starting point for this sort of thing ought to be [DocumentBuilder](http://ericwhite.com/blog/documentbuilder-expanded/)

In Java, you can use MergeDocx (which I wrote). Its also available for C#/.NET, in case you want something only it can do.